# How to use GridSearchCV for one-class classification

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

I tried to use GridSearchCV in order to have the best parameters for my classifier. I am using the one-class SVM, and my code is:

```
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5],
                 'nu': [0.001, 0.10, 0.1, 10, 25, 50, 100, 1000]},
                {'kernel': ['linear'], 'nu': [0.001, 0.10, 0.1, 10, 25, 50, 100, 1000]}
               ] 

scores = ['precision', 'recall']

for score in scores:
  print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
  print()

 clf = GridSearchCV(svm.OneClassSVM(), tuned_parameters,
                   scoring='%s_macro' % score)
 clf.fit(input_dataN)
```

i got errors :

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'
```

How to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the fit method you need to supply your features (X_train) as well as your target class labels (y_train):

Fix this line:

```
clf.fit(input_dataN)
```

Comment: I used one-class classification, I have not y_train.

Comment: If you only have positive labels then you are restricted with that you can do. [this link might be useful](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192530/metrics-for-one-class-classification)